# Encrypt every item inside a folder in Bash

Tags: bash, aes, cbc-mac

I have a code which is supposed to encrypt every file within a folder but when I put it (the encryption code) within the infinite loop it does not work.

```
touch Out_file.txt
ls > Out_file.txt
i = 0
while:
i = i + 1
line=$(head -n $i Out_file.txt)
openssl cbc -aes-256-cbc -pass pass:Hello123  -p -in $line -out $line.enc
done
```

> It might be able to encrypt all your files within the folder you are
>   running the program in so please proceed with caution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

(just simplifying how we generate the list of files and run through them)

```
touch Out_file.txt
#write only filename to Out_file.txt
ls -l | awk 'NF>1{print $NF}' > Out_file.txt
while read filename; do
  openssl cbc -aes-256-cbc -pass pass:Hello123  -p -in $filename -out $filename.enc
done <Out_file.txt
```

Good Luck.